# Custom slider issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created custom slider but it's not working, can you guys please guide me.

My code:

```
var mwth = 0;
var count = 0;
var wth = 0;
var twth = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box-wrap .box:odd').css("background", "#0C0");
    mwth = $('.box-wrap').width();
    count = $('.box-wrap .box').size();
    wth = $('.box-wrap .box').width();
    twth = (count) * (wth + 2)

    $('.box-wrap .box').wrapAll("<div class='slider-wp'>");
    $(".slider-wp").css("width", twth);


    for (i = 0; i < (twth / mwth); i++) {
        $(".box-wrap").append("<a href='#'>test</a>")
    }

    $(".box-wrap a").each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            banner_slide((index) * 990);
            return;

        });
    });

    setInterval(banner_slider, 1000);


});

function banner_slide(i) {
    $(".slider-wp").animate({
        left: "-" + i + ""
    }, 1000).delay(1000);

}

function banner_slider(cnt) {
    twth = (count) * (wth + 2)
    var j = 1000;
    for (i = 0; i <= (twth - 990); i = i + 990) {
        j = j + 1000;
        $(".slider-wp").animate({
            left: "-" + i + ""
        }, 1000).delay(j);
    }
}
```

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anuragaadi/DBWTd/embedded/result).

Comment: What is the issue. What do you want the slider to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your issue is the fact that upon clicking the links to an individual frame, the right frame isn't animated to.

The reason why this is happening is because you are seemingly precalculating the animation of the slider several frames at a time.

```
for (i = 0; i <= (twth - 990); i = i + 990) {
    j = j + 1000;
    $(".slider-wp").animate({
        left: "-" + i + ""
    }, 1000).delay(j);
}
```

If you modify your animation code to work frame-by-frame like so:

```
var frame = 0;
function banner_slider(cnt){
    frame ++;
    if (frame > 4) frame = 0;    
    banner_slide(frame * 990);    
}
```

You won't run into trouble. Plus this uses the function you had previously created for a similar task ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBWTd/1/) for you so you can see it in action. The slider itself is far from complete (feel free to ask anything if you're stuck) but this should solve your immediate issue and get you on your way. Good luck!

Comment: perfect work thanks, can i know your name